# How to get the Today Date (Only Date not DateTime) and Current Year End Date in JavaScript LWC Salesforce

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, javascript, lightning-web-components, lightning-design-system

I want to display default date values to Lightning-Input, how to get the Today Date and Current year date in Javascript.
Format should be :- May 15, 2020

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following can get you current date

JS

```
connectedCallback(){
    var today = new Date();
    this.date=today.toISOString();
    console.log(today.toISOString())
    var last=new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), 11, 32);
    this.date1=last.toISOString();
}
```

here is a PG https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/9NLbuG8pA/3/edit

Comment: Thanks, and also i have one more date input field to default the current year end date i.e Dec 31, 2020

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, the answer from @User6670 is going to give you time zone headaches where the "today" calculation is concerned.  Say you have a user in California who accesses your component on May 15, 2020 at 5pm (their time).  Since they have a time zone offset of 7 hours, they will see "May 16, 2020" -- the date in UTC.

To fix this, adjust for the user's local time zone:

```js
// Get the current date/time in UTC
let rightNow = new Date();

// Adjust for the user's time zone
rightNow.setMinutes(
    new Date().getMinutes() - new Date().getTimezoneOffset()
);

// Return the date in "YYYY-MM-DD" format
let yyyyMmDd = rightNow.toISOString().slice(0,10);
console.log(yyyyMmDd); // Displays the user's current date, e.g. "2020-05-15"
```

Playground example: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/vdbsMDBPP/4/edit

Comment: Thanks Matthew Souther